# reducing insert statement time when dealing with large amount of data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I read about SqlBulkCopy and the way it can reduce the amount of time used when inserting large amount of rows my scenario is : I have a an excel file wish I convert it into a dataTable then I send this dataTable to a stored procedure ( wish I can't change its code ) that insert all the rows in the dataTable to an sql table in the database

the problem is that I have like 10 000 to 50 000 rows to insert is there any work around to reduce the time took by the stored procedure ?

Comment: not clear at all... You want to use SqlBulkCopy, or your SP, or Bulk INSERT in your SP ? You can change the code of your SP, or not (I don't understand `wish I can't change its code`)

Comment: Unless you can change the stored procedure, you can't use SqlBulkCopy as the stored proc is doing this at the moment. The only ways you will be able to reduce are environmental i.e. turning the recovery mode to simple. You could possible reduce the size of you table and instead of sending 50000 rows send say 1000 at a time? As I don't know what this SP is actually doing it's hard to give more help than that.

Comment: As far as i know `SqlBulkCopy` does not work with stored-procedures. So if you don't need the SP you can insert the 50000 rows with `SqlBulkCopy` very fast. It supports also `DataTable` as input. [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

Comment: so the best way is to send a piece of the dataTable at a time ?

Comment: You can do this sort of thing against the database directly using SSIS packages.

Comment: i can't mess up with the database isn't there a way in my server side to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use SqlBulkCopy to add the data to a temporary table and then feed that data into the stored proc. You will need to write some SQL code to do the processing but the performance benefits of doing it this way should be worth the effort.

If you create a new stored proc then you have the added benefit of running all of this code inside the database engine so you will not be switching back and forth between your application and the DB engine.

Some Code:

```
    var importData = new DataSet();
    xmlData.Position = 0;
    importData.ReadXml(xmlData);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
      using (var trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
      {
        using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, trans) { DestinationTableName = myTableName })
        {
          foreach (DataColumn col in importData.Tables[0].Columns)
          {
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
          }

          sbc.WriteToServer(importData.Tables[0]); //table 0 is the main table in this dataset

          // Now lets call the stored proc.
          var cmd = new SqlCommand("ProcessDataImport", connection)
              {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
              };
          cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          trans.Commit();
        }
        connection.Close();
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Where XmlData is a stream with the Xml data matching your bulk import and myTableName contains the table you want to import into. Rememeber, when doing a bulk copy, the column names must match 100%. Case is important too.

The proc would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProcessDataImport]
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @IMPORTCOL INT

  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT X FROM TEMPTABLE)
  BEGIN
    SELECT @IMPORTCOL = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN1 FROM TEMPTABLE)
    EXEC DOTHEIMPORT @IMPORTCOL
    DELETE FROM TEMPTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = @IMPORTCOL
  END
END
```

Comment: can u provide an example or a link that can be useful to read ? please

Comment: what should be the DestinationTableName ? bcs in my case i don't know what is the Table Name it's a stored Procedure it can contains multiple Tables

Comment: The destination table would be a new table that you create where the columns match the parameters for the stored proc that you need to call. The new stored proc that you create would then retrieve the parameters from the new temp table and call the existing stored proc for each row in the temp table.